# How to solve differential equation with integrating factor method?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I need to solve first order differential equation of this type:

$$\dfrac{\partial T_1}{\partial T_0} + a \dfrac{T_1}{T_0} = f (T_0)$$

I know it need to be integrating factor method, but I don`t know how to write that in Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome! At this site, we expect that one places the Mathematica code, rather than formulas in the form of TEX or images. Please have a look here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour. Concerning your question, please check Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/DSolve and try this: `DSolve[D[T1[T0], T0] + a*T1[T0]/T0 == f[T0], T1, T0]`

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica `DSolve` is smart enough to use this method automatically.

```
ClearAll[T, t, f, a];
ode = T'[t] + a T[t] == f[t]
DSolve[ode, T[t], t]
```

$$
\left\{\left\{T(t)\to e^{-a t} \int _1^te^{a K[1]} f(K[1])dK[1]+c_1 e^{-a
   t}\right\}\right\}
$$

By hand to verify:

The ODE is
\begin{align*} 
         T' +a T &= f \left(t \right)
\end{align*}
The integrating factor $\mu$ is
\begin{align*} 
                \mu &= {\mathrm e}^{\int a d t}\\ 
                     &= {\mathrm e}^{a t}
\end{align*}

Therefore the ode becomes
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}\left( \mu T\right) &= \left(\mu \right) \left(f \left(t \right)\right) \\ 
\frac{\mathop{\mathrm{d}}}{ \mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} \left(T \,{\mathrm e}^{a t}\right) &= \left({\mathrm e}^{a t}\right) \left(f \left(t \right)\right)\\ 
        \mathrm{d} \left(T \,{\mathrm e}^{a t}\right)  &= \left({\mathrm e}^{a t} f \left(t \right)\right)\, \mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}

Integrating gives
\begin{align*}
T \,{\mathrm e}^{a t} &= \int {\mathrm e}^{a t} f \left(t \right)d t + c_1 
\end{align*}
Dividing both sides by the integrating factor $\mu={\mathrm e}^{a t}$ results in
\begin{align*}
          T &= {\mathrm e}^{-a t} \left(\int {\mathrm e}^{a t} f \left(t \right)d t \right)+c_{1} {\mathrm e}^{-a t}
\end{align*}
which simplifies to
\begin{align*}
          T &= {\mathrm e}^{-a t} \left(\int {\mathrm e}^{a t} f \left(t \right)d t +c_{1}\right)
\end{align*}

Mathematica likes to write the final integral starting from 1 to $t$ and that is why  it uses `K[1]` inside the integral instead of $t$. It is the same thing as the above. Where the integral starts from is not important. it can be zero or 1. Since the difference is absorbed in the constant of integration.